# EF Core Relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have problem constructing my relationships.

I want every `Post` to has **one User** and many `Comments`. Every `User` to have many `Comments` and `Posts` (if I want anytime to filter comments and posts per User). And then every `Comment` to has **one User and Post**

The problem is when I seed the db

```
if (!ctx.Posts.Any()) {
    Tag tag = new Tag() {
        Name = "Test1"
    };

    User user = new User() {
        UserName = "TestUser",
        Email = "test1@test1.bg",
        Password = Extensions.PasswordHash("abv123456", config["AppSettings:PasswordSalt"]),
        Role = UserRoles.Member
    };

    ctx.Users.Add(user);

    Post post = new Post() {
        Title = "Test Post",
        Description = "Description post test",
        Likes = 5,
        User = user,
        CreateOn = DateTime.Now,
        LastEditOn = DateTime.Now
    };

    PostTag posttags = new PostTag() {
        Post = post,
        Tag = tag
    };

    ctx.PostTag.Add(posttags);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
};
```

And If I want to fetch all posts with the related `User`

```
public IActionResult GetAllPost() {
    var posts = _ctx.Posts
        .Include(u => u.User)
        .ToList();

    return Json(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(posts));
}
```

I get **Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected with type 'Blog.Data.Entities.Post'. Path '[0].User.Posts'.**

While in my `Configure` method I did ignore it

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts => {
    opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

**OnModelCreating()**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    // set unique email and username
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasIndex(u => new { u.Email, u.UserName })
        .IsUnique();

    // set unique tag name
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
        .HasIndex(t => t.Name)
        .IsUnique();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasOne(p => p.User)
        .WithMany(u => u.Posts);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Comments)
        .WithOne(u => u.User);

    // post tag many-to-many rel
    modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
        .HasKey(pt => new { pt.PostUID, pt.TagUID });

    modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
        .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostUID);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
        .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
        .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
        .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagUID);
}
```

Comment: I think the question should be edited off EF since this has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to JSONify a JSON string:

```
return Json(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(posts));
```

You need to let the framework do it for you, instead:

```
return Json(posts);
```

Comment: This is one of the problem.  I will solve the double JSON conversion but not the loop.  @Denisx, you should remove navigation properties of your model when it's not needed.

Comment: @hugo What loop are you talking about? And who told you that navigation property isn't needed? Just because it provokes an unneeded self-reference here it doesn't mean it's not useful in the rest of the application.

Comment: E.g. If you don't need the reference to User into the Post class, why do you bother with it?  I don't say there is such reference but if not needed, you should avoid it.  One navigation property in one class is enough to create the relation and the foreign key in most of the cases.  And during Json conversion, you avoid loop reference problems.  Reason of my previous comment.

Comment: @hugo Again, where did you read the OP doesn't need that relationship? Being a reference, the runtime cost is completely negligible and removing it would probably cause confusion to another developer making them ask themselves why the reference isn't there

Comment: Remove the Newtonsoft serialization solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've configured your service, but you're not using the service. You're using a static reference to Newtonsoft Json converter. You either need to use the service provided by framework (it should use it automatically when returning a model from a controller), or apply the configuration to the Newtonsoft Json converter call that you're using.